# convert an array returned by mysql into html php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following tables in my db

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `category`
--

CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `heading` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `category`
--

INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `heading`, `slug`) VALUES
(1, 'Main Cat 1', 'main-cat-1'),
(2, 'Main Cat 2', 'main-cat-2');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `subcategory`
--

CREATE TABLE `subcategory` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `heading` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `subcategory`
--

INSERT INTO `subcategory` (`id`, `cat_id`, `heading`, `slug`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Sub Cat 1', 'sub-cat-1'),
(2, 1, 'Sub Cat 2', 'sub-cat-2'),
(3, 2, 'Sub Cat 3', 'sub-cat-3'),
(4, 2, 'Sub Cat 4', 'sub-cat-4');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `category`
--
ALTER TABLE `category`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `subcategory`
--
ALTER TABLE `subcategory`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `category`
--
ALTER TABLE `category`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `subcategory`
--
ALTER TABLE `subcategory`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
```

The query I used to fetch data from the tables is

```
    "SELECT
    `category`.`id` AS `mainId`
    , `subcategory`.`id` AS `subId`
    , `category`.`heading` AS `mainHead`
    , `subcategory`.`heading` AS `subHead`
    , `category`.`slug` AS `mainSlug`
    , `subcategory`.`slug` AS `subSlug`
 FROM
    `category`
    INNER JOIN `subcategory` 
        ON (`category`.`id` = `subcategory`.`cat_id`)"
```

and the resultant array is

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [mainId] => 1
            [subId] => 1
            [mainHead] => Main Cat 1
            [subHead] => Sub Cat 1
            [mainSlug] => main-cat-1
            [subSlug] => sub-cat-1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [mainId] => 1
            [subId] => 2
            [mainHead] => Main Cat 1
            [subHead] => Sub Cat 2
            [mainSlug] => main-cat-1
            [subSlug] => sub-cat-2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [mainId] => 2
            [subId] => 3
            [mainHead] => Main Cat 2
            [subHead] => Sub Cat 3
            [mainSlug] => main-cat-2
            [subSlug] => sub-cat-3
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [mainId] => 2
            [subId] => 4
            [mainHead] => Main Cat 2
            [subHead] => Sub Cat 4
            [mainSlug] => main-cat-2
            [subSlug] => sub-cat-4
        )

)
```

I need the output html to be like

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <ul>
        <li>Main Cat 1</li>
        <li><a href="example.com/mainSlug/subSlug">Sub Cat 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="example.com/mainSlug/subSlug">Sub Cat 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <ul>
        <li>Main Cat 2</li>
        <li><a href="example.com/mainSlug/subSlug">Sub Cat 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="example.com/mainSlug/subSlug">Sub Cat 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this? I'm using CodeIgniter Active Record to fetch the result.

Comment: Iterate the array using `foreach`

Comment: Please review [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) to better understand how voting works, and that everyone here is entitled to vote however they wish.  [It's also not appropriate to make demands within your OP regarding votes or anything else that is not directly relevant to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Easy.. simply Iterate the array or Object. Like this:

```
<?php $restaurants; //suppose this is your restaurants array? ?>
<?php foreach($restaurants as $res) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul>
            <li><?php print $res['mainHead']?></li>
            <li><a href="example.com/mainSlug/subSlug"><?php print $res['subHead']?></a></li>
            <li><a href="example.com/mainSlug/subSlug"><?php print $res['subHead']?></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Looks like your case is object. try this if the first example wont work:

```
<?php foreach($restaurants as $res) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul>
            <li><?php print $res->mainHead?></li>
            <li><a href="example.com/mainSlug/subSlug"><?php print $res->subHead?></a></li>
            <li><a href="example.com/mainSlug/subSlug"><?php print $res->subHead?></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply@Ilan Hasanov,but i think you didn't get my question....
here the mainId is repeating in each object, but i want to categorize the output with the mainId, ie the mainId or mainHead (eg: Main Cat 1, Main Cat 2) should only apper once. If you check the desired output i need you will understand what i'm looking for. Its like a tree kind of output